# Why `::before` adds some height when using content `url(svg)`

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
  <div class="details"><button className="details-btn"></button>
  <div>
  <p className="title">Some content
  </p>
  </div>
```

With the following styles

```
.details {
  display: flex
}

button::before {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml; utf8, <svg width="13" height="14" viewBox="0 0 13 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M4.38128 4.61866L5.61872 3.38123L9.23743 6.99994L5.61872 10.6187L4.38128 9.38123L6.76256 6.99994L4.38128 4.61866Z" fill="black"/></svg>')
}
```

I want to center the image coming from `::before` with the paragraph. The problem is that even though my svg has height of 14, the resulting height of the `::before` element is `15`. Why and how can I fix that (I have to use `::before`)